# Kotlin Drawer activity onclick event listner

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener

I've started a new android project in Kotlin using the default Navigation Drawer Activity
Minimum SDK api 28

My IDE is android studio 4.0.1

Then I run on my mobile to test. App compiles with success
But I think click event listener is missing.
Toggle menu works fine, but once click views never change, and can not find a way to switch between different menu's intent/fragments

I've found many different post about Navigation Drawer using `onNavigationItemSelected`, but none uses the latest version.

I've tried to implement `onOptionsItemSelected`, but can not find a clear doc for that

So if you can help me with that, I'll be grateful :)
... and sorry for my poor English

[image]
Url repo on github => https://github.com/TVart/NavDrawerActivity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's an ordering issue in the project template. In the `activity_main.xml` file, change

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    ... />

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    ... />
```

to

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    ... />
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    ... />
```

The example app should work after this. As to why the ordering matters, check out the official documentation for `DrawerLayout`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout

Here is the important part:

> To use a DrawerLayout, position your **primary content view as the
> first child** with width and height of match_parent and no
> layout_gravity>. Add **drawers as child views after the main content
> view** and set the layout_gravity appropriately. Drawers commonly use
> match_parent for height with a fixed width.

Comment: Noticed the downvote. Please elaborate why, as the answer is a working solution, tested on the provided repo.